# How can I delete specific sentences along with the next one?

Tags: python, parsing

I'm processing a transcript in a text file and I need to get rid of a few specific lines.

Here is an example:

```
Child:    Mom   can   I    have  an  ice cream?
grammar:  noun  verb  pro  verb  art noun
Mom:      Here is   some  money, go    buy   that  ice cream
grammar:  adv  verb pro   noun   verb  verb  pro   noun
Child:    But  I   want more money, I   want the  big  ice cream
grammar:  conj pro verb adj  noun   pro verb art  adj  noun
```

What Python script can I use if I want to delete all the mom's sentences and the following grammar sentence, where I want to keep the grammar sentences of the child?

Comment: please post your desired output.

Comment: Sorry... In python...

Comment: And I want only the sentences of the child and the grammars of the child. Does that make sense?

Comment: Also, in the txt file it's on different lines, so one line for the child, next line is the grammar, next line is mom and so on...

Comment: Read *two* lines at a time and decide on the first word of the first line.

Answer (score 1):

It reads from file lazily and in pairs, and skip yielding value on specific condition. Code below function dumps filtered lines to another file.

```
def yield_filtered_lines(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        while True:
            sentence = f.readline()
            grammar = f.readline()
            if not sentence or not grammar:
                break  # EOF
            if sentence.startswith("Mom:"):
                continue
            yield sentence
            yield grammar

with open('filtered.txt', 'w') as f:
    for l in yield_filtered_lines("sentences.txt"):
        f.write(l)
```

`sentences.txt` content:

```
Child:    Mom   can   I    have  an  ice cream?
grammar:  noun  verb  pro  verb  art noun
Mom:      Here is   some  money, go    buy   that  ice cream
grammar:  adv  verb pro   noun   verb  verb  pro   noun
Child:    But  I   want more money, I   want the  big  ice cream
grammar:  conj pro verb adj  noun   pro verb art  adj  noun
```

`filtered.txt` content:

```
Child:    Mom   can   I    have  an  ice cream?
grammar:  noun  verb  pro  verb  art noun
Child:    But  I   want more money, I   want the  big  ice cream
grammar:  conj pro verb adj  noun   pro verb art  adj  noun
```

Comment: Almost... But I only want the output show the child's sentence and the grammar sentence following the child sentence. I want the "mom" sentence and the grammar following the mom gone... So I have an output file with what the child says, and the grammar of the child's sentence

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

- iterate over your text file using a *for loop*
- for each line in the file, test the beginning of it eg. line.startswith("Child:")
- if True, write that line to a new file (opened before starting the *for loop*)

Just translate the above into python code and you're good

Comment: Don't know why this was down voted, but its perfectly OK for me to just give an explanation instead of code, if the OP doesn't even offer one line of code by himself.

Comment: This will not do the task as asked, it will only write out the lines that start with that phrase and not the next one as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('input.txt') as infile, open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for quote in infile:
        grammar = next(infile)
        if quote.startswith('Child'):
            outfile.write(quote + grammar)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a namedTemporaryFile and shutil.move to replace the original file:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from shutil import move

with open('in.txt') as f, NamedTemporaryFile(dir=".", delete=False) as out:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("Child"):
            out.writelines((line,next(f)))

move(out.name, "temp.txt")
```